# Convert float 32 bit big endian to little endian

Tags: c, image-processing

My data is a 2d 32 bit 2-D pointer image which is in big endian and I wish to convert in to little endian. Please check the following code:

```
  float** ReverseFloat( const float **inFloat )
 {
   float **retVal;
   char *floatToConvert = ( char* ) && inFloat;
   char *returnFloat = ( char* ) && retVal;

   // swap the bytes into a temporary buffer
   returnFloat[0] = floatToConvert[3];
   returnFloat[1] = floatToConvert[2];
   returnFloat[2] = floatToConvert[1];
   returnFloat[3] = floatToConvert[0];

   return retVal;
 }
```

Hi. As per all of your advice, I tried the following code but it gives all zero values:

```
float **swapend( float **in ,float **out , int h, int v)
{
  char *floatToConvert = ( char* ) & in;
  char *returnFloat = ( char *) & out;
  for (int m=0; m<h; m++)
    for (int k=0; k<v; k++)
    {
      for (int i=0; i<sizeof(float); i++)
        returnFloat[sizeof(float)-1-i] = floatToConvert[i];
    }

  return out;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the code ***work***? If not, what is wrong with it? What is the question here?

Comment: Not sure why you pass in and out pointers of pointers: you could simply pass the floats directly? Other than that, codereview.stackexchange.com is meant for that kind of question (that is, if the code *works* already).

Comment: sorry but my question is , since i have 2 d array i am not sure how to convert each n all values of this array which is stored in a 2d pointer. Therefore i am unable to check if the code already runs

Comment: The code given doesn't even compile. Are you sure it's C and not C++? (even then, it doesn't look like valid C++)

Comment: please help i have editied my question

Answer (score 2):

This won't work reliably. You create a local variable `retVal` and at the end, you return it. The value of this variable will eventually be random after the function ends.

I think this approach would be better since the compiler will do most of the necessary copying:

```
float be2le( char * floatToConvert ) {
     float buffer;
     char * returnFloat = (char *) &buffer;

     ...swap...

     return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do I add all the float values big endien from the 2d pointer of image for this swapping ?

Comment: You'd have to do each element in a loop

Comment: @user3840066: Your new code only converts the first float. You need to use `out[m][k] = be2le(&in[m][k])` in the loop + use my function.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is the [*logical and* operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) (it may also carry a pointer like semantic as a gnu extension, but this is non portable), while `&` is the ["address of” operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access).  You don't need to use pointers of pointers either:

```
float ReverseFloat(float inFloat ){
  float retVal;
  char *floatToConvert = ( char* ) &inFloat;
  char *returnFloat = ( char* ) &retVal;

  // swap the bytes into a temporary buffer
  returnFloat[0] = floatToConvert[3];
  returnFloat[1] = floatToConvert[2];
  returnFloat[2] = floatToConvert[1];
  returnFloat[3] = floatToConvert[0];
  return retVal;
}
```

Note that this function works both ways: it let you convert from one endianness to the other.

Following your update: if you wish to convert several values contained in an array, just apply this function on each of them sequentially:

```
void ReverseFloatArray(unsigned int count, float *in, float *out){
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        out[i] = ReverseFloat(in[i]);
 }
```

Comment: `&&` is also a GNU-C extension for label address (which is how it's parsed in this case)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen thank you! I'm not used to gnu extensions. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It seems all the points in your question have been fullfilled. Please don't further change it to reflect new requirements: this is bad etiquette. Instead create a new question and accept an answer for this one.